# Different behavior of capacitor-rate-app plugin in android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, vuejs2, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am using -  https://github.com/Nodonisko/capacitor-rate-app, plugin to implement in-app-review functionality in my Vue app.

Different behavior has been noticed for android and ios.

for iOS, when app-review popup comes on screen and user click outside, the popup still persist on screen.
but in android, clicking outside other than the popup makes the app-review popup disappear.

Is it the normal behavior? what I could do from my side to make behavior common for both.

Comment: These popups likely implement the ways that the operating systems intend popups. This means that the users (on their own device!) knows how popups ususally behave and will not be confused if you just keep it

Comment: Thanks Torge. Even I got reply back from owner of capacitor-rate-app repo on github - https://github.com/Nodonisko/capacitor-rate-app/issues/58.
So, yeah It's not gonna provide bad user experience.